# How to use media print within Reactjs web app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

I would like to hide a div when print preview happens but I find it almost impossible to do it in a React.

```
<div className="contacts"></div>
```

Is there any possibilities that I can add pure css or if React Stylesheet supports **@media print** and hide element with class name contacts when print preview.

I was reading this article https://blog.logrocket.com/the-best-react-inline-style-libraries-comparing-radium-aphrodite-emotion-849ef148c473 but it just seems too much work for something that I would do poorly in css within a matter of seconds.

Any idea how can I achieve such thing in Reactjs?

Comment: `import './styles.css';`?

Comment: how about inline css?

Comment: See my answer below for as close to inline media queries as you can get

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inline media queries are not possible. The closest you can get is inlining a stylesheet, like so (in React syntax):

```
<div className="contacts">
  <style>
    {`@media print {.contacts{display: none;}}`}
  </style>
</div>
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, also since I am developing using typescript import './styles.css'; it does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 7):

A bit old but maybe it will be useful for someone. If you want to use React styles you can also do:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    contacts:{
      display: "block",
    },
    [`@media print`]: {
      contacts:{
        display: "none",
      },
    }
  }))
...
const classes = useStyles();
...
<div className={classes.contacts}></div>
```

This markup works for me with `FunctionComponents` flawlesly.

Comment: Thank you this is literally what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use media queries (also pseudo-classes and pseudo-selectors) inside inline styles. You need to extract your css into a sepparate `.css` file and to import it either inside your component's file (if you use bundlers like webpack) or just include it inside your html with `<link>` tag